# Scheduled event to copy data from one table to another in MySQL returns empty results

Tags: mysql, sql, events, copy, sql-insert

**Running on phpMyAdmin local server:**
I have two tables: `user` (with data) and `user_t` (empty).
They have identical column name, order and type (the `user_t` table has one extra column for timestamping the input though).

I want to create a `scheduled event` to check if the `timestamp` of each user's log has a certain value and when it does, I want to copy it to `user_t` while deleting it from `user`. Pretty straightforward.

The deletion works fine. It is the `INSERT INTO user_t SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.reg < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;` that gives me trouble.

**This is the code I am using to create the event:**

```
CREATE EVENT users_u
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO 
INSERT INTO user_t SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.reg < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
DELETE FROM user WHERE reg < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
```

However, it keeps returning `empty result`. So, I take it there must be something I am doing wrong.
Could you find it in your hearts to help me make this code work? After all, it is from a tutorial and should be fine.

I have tried playing with the code and even considered looking into `transaction` but that seemed too bulky for this kind of operation.

## EDIT

So after some playing with the code from [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk), I finally figured it out and here is the code that worked for me (I generalised the table and column names so they would not mislead anyone):

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event_name 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
DO 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO empty_table (col_name1, col_name2, col_name3, col_name4, col_name5) 
    SELECT col_name1, col_name2, col_name3, col_name4, col_name5 FROM data_table WHERE col_name < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE; 
    DELETE FROM data_table WHERE col_name < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE; 
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hopefully it helps someone like me in the future.
Thanks again, [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk), for your quick help. Much appreciated and, of course, your answer is CORRECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run every minute the event and want to enter the last three minutes, i dount that you have that many new inserts, or you need a python script or so that inserts for one hour
==> for testing purposes, I set up the frequency to 1 minute...

Still you should rewrite your event.

first do you really want duplicates, maybe a `INSERT IGNORE`,which would enter new row, if it violates a constraint

second if you have mire than one statement you need a `BEGIN END`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT users_u
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO 
    BEGIN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO user_t SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.reg < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
        DELETE FROM user WHERE reg < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the frequency of schedule is only for testing.. I do not want to wait 24 hours to see if it works as it should.. As for the code, thank you but it returns `an unexpected error`.. probably the delimiter??? I should add that I am running this in phpMyAdmin...

Comment: you need the delimiter only in workbench where i tested it , so you can remove them and give a try

Comment: ok, so the problem was in the fact that in your code, you forgot to close the delimiter (`$$` after `END`).. I hope you don't mind I edited it in your post...
but even with the delimiter functioning, the `result returns empty`...

Comment: the code works, if you haven't any data, you have a problem first create like in th example some test tadat that are older than 3 minutes and then create the event.  https://dbfiddle.uk/7PTDgrA3

Comment: Thank you very much.. I did stay with `insert into` without `ignore` and it does exactly what I want it to.. but I would not have known about the delimiters without you.. \/ thanks.